# Class member template function call not being deducted

Tags: c++, templates

I am having trouble understanding why the following does not compile. I have the following code like so (some code ommited):

Header:

```
template <typename KeyType, typename ElementType>
class TUnorderedMap
{
public:
    ElementType* Find(const KeyType Key);
    const ElementType* Find(const KeyType Key) const;
};

struct Foo
{
};
```

Source file:

```
void Lookup()
{
    TUnorderedMap <Foo*, Foo> NodeToWidgetLookup;
    
    Foo TempFoo;
    const Foo* SelectionTarget = &TempFoo;

    // Issue here in this call
    NodeToWidgetLookup.Find(SelectionTarget);

    // Issue here in this call
    NodeToWidgetLookup.Find(SelectionTarget);
}
```

Error message:
[image: ErrorMessage]
What is the issue here? Why is neither of the Find functions accepted?

Comment: do not omit code if it does not make sense anymore afterwards

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: What does not make sense? The code is self-sustained but I will organize it.

Comment: Use [this](https://godbolt.org/z/qhW5v5fda) to provide [mcve].

Comment: After patching typos and missing code and can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/x5j76jKeM linking issue comes up.

Comment: @MarekR you are missing the const in line 14

Comment: This question is a variation of "Why is a mutable pointer to a const object not a const pointer to a mutable object?"

Comment: Yes I'm aweare - this is one of patches, since Find will not accept  `const` value. Note `const` without initialization is bad thing.

Comment: Revised typos and structure. Thanks for input.

Comment: See gcc error message should be more clear: https://godbolt.org/z/8KfdevYe7

Comment: `const Foo *` is something different then `Foo * const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the issue here? Why is neither of the Find functions accepted?

With the given instantiation

```
TUnorderedMap <Foo*, Foo> NodeToWidgetLookup;
```

The function `Find` expects a **const pointer** `Foo *const`:

```
const ElementType* Find(Foo* const Key) const;
```

While you are trying to pass a **non-const pointer to const** argument `const Foo*`:

```
const Foo* SelectionTarget
```

---

You can either change the template arguments like this:

```
TUnorderedMap <const Foo*, Foo> NodeToWidgetLookup;
```

Or make your argument point to a non-const instance:

```
Foo* SelectionTarget;
```

If you want to take all **pointer** overloads, you may want to declare an overload that is a function template itself:

```
template<typename Key>
const ElementType* Find(const Key* key) const {
    static_assert(std::is_same<Key*, KeyType>::value, "The types don't match");
    ...
}
```

The template ignores cv-qualifiers of the pointed to object of and the (outermost) pointer part of the argument, but it won't be applicable for non-pointer types.

Thanks to overload resolution rules you also can mix it with a non-template overload:

```
ElementType* Find(const KeyType Key);
const ElementType* Find(const KeyType Key) const;
template<typename Key> const ElementType* Find(const Key* key) const;
```

But be advised, that non-template functions in this scenario precede the function template in the overload resolution candidate list.

Comment: Yes, #3 was the solution that I had in mind but was unsure if there was some kind of template black magic that could encompass all of the pointer overloads in one. Thanks for your answer